# Using a Raspberry Pi 4 for motor control

Tags: dc-motor

I am fairly new to electronics and am trying to build a drone from scratch as a hobby project. I want a setup where I can control all the motors individually through the software. Through some research I found that ESCs are the way to go for BLDC motors, and I am planning on getting [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08XM2DF4C). I also came across this post which is almost identical to the thing that I am trying to do, except that I am using a Raspberry Pi. After multiple failed purchases due to not knowing what would work with my setup, I am reluctant to buy this and want to know how to connect it before the purchase.

This is the diagram of the ESC:
[image: diagram]

My biggest worry is that the Raspberry Pi's diagram only has 2 PWM (pulse width modulation) pins (32, 33):

[image: raspberry pi pin diagram]

How would I connect these 2 to have access to the speeds of all the motors individually?

Comment: Without a specification of the device you may get speculation. A picture  is meaningless.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a specification of the required PWM signals and the resolution required for your project. Software PWM might be an option.

Comment: Whoops the link didn't stick. It's there now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general consensus appears to be that because it is not a Real Time system, a Raspberry Pi is not a suitable device to use directly as a Flight Controller.  While it is technically possible, an Arduino or a Raspberry Pi Pico (or a dedicated FC) would be better choice for use as a Flight Controller and then use the Raspberry Pi to talk to the Flight Controller/

Here are some sites to review:

https://www.reddit.com/r/diydrones/comments/t254dc/pwm_and_raspberry_pi_as_fc_how_to_communicate/

https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=306388

https://www.instructables.com/The-Drone-Pi/

https://all3dp.com/2/raspbery-pi-drone-simply-explained/

or just google "raspberry pi as a flight controller"

Comment: Thanks! Seems like if I want to run anything like machine learning on the drone, I am going to need to connect the pi to an arduino (or some other flight controller) to do so. Thanks for the links!